# Symbolic link not working on nginx

Tags: symlink, nginx

Nginx is working fine with root path without symbolic links(Eg.../1.0/public). When a symbolic link is used(Eg.../current/public where current is a link to 2.0) the changes don't get affected until I change the name of the old target folder. I am using nginx version 1.13.6.

I have given `disable_symlinks off;` in my nginx.conf. Can someone tell me how to specify root path with symbolic links in nginx and use those links to point to different targets without restarting nginx so that the UX is not disturbed and the change is seamless?

Comment: Would an nginx reload not be enough?   Not a restart, but "kill -HUP" of nginx' PID.

Comment: Yes. But, that would break any existing HTTP connections. So, I would prefer using symbolic links to redirect to the targets. I have other applications being served through nginx on the same VPS as well.

Comment: A reload does not "break" existing connections, that's what it's for.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I got this done using symlinks and my answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because fastCGI was caching the path. 
When the line in the nginx config:

`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` in the php location block was replaced with:

```
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

every change gets affected immediately.

Comment: This concurs with this other popular answer: https://serverfault.com/a/848526/119666